# How to use NITF in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml

I need to create one sample application for NITF-News Industry Text Format in iphone. I don't know how to begin. What Language(Css,Javascript like that..) should i use to read the content from .xml(NITF) files and design the article pages in iphone.I red from this [Link](http://www.iptc.org/site/News_Exchange_Formats/NITF/). NITF uses the eXtensible Markup Language(xml) to define the content and structure of news articles.

Please anyone give me some guidance to start.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NSXmlParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to parse the data.. Then display the content accordingly..